# Can i run Selenium WebDriver visible browser window?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can i run Selenium WebDriver visible browser window?
I mean all the code will work seamlessly for the user.

Comment: Please try clearly state the question you are asking. 
What do you want to run in the browser window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can simply import time and insert a time.sleep(10) call to sleep 10 seconds while you manually interact with the open browser window. Selenium should resume where it left off once the sleep timer is expired.

```
import time

time.sleep(10)
```